# removing the tail of a linked list with a tail pointer

Tags: c

I'm trying to create a function that removes the tail of a linked list.  I have both a head and tail pointer, so my question is, when I'm trying to remove from the tail, do I still need to traverse the list to remove the node at the tail?

Comment: post a [mcve] please.

Comment: if it is a single-linked head-to-tail list, then yes. You have to enumerate the list. The only benefit to managing a tail pointer is a single-linked list is O(1) insertion time at the tail. No other list operation gains benefit. Draw a chain of boxes and arrows, with two extra arrows, head and tail, pointing to their respective nodes, on a piece of paper. Look at the drawing, then ask yourself what needs to be updated to keep the list intact if I want to delete that node pointed to by tail. Then consider what must be done to get there.

Comment: Why are you not using a doubly linked list?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that your list is a singly linked list, you still need to traverse it, because the second to last element becomes the new tail and it should be updated.
So, storing the list's tail, is not a great idea.

Instead, if you have a doubly linked list, you can freed the tail and update it, following the "back link".

Answer (score 1):

As part of removing the node, you need the node preceding the node to remove for two reasons:

- `tail` needs to be updated to point to it.
- Its `next` field needs to be set to `NULL`.

Before:

```
head         Node             Node          Node          tail
+------+     +-------+        +-------+     +-------+     +------+
|    ------->|     -----...-->|     ------->| NULL  |<-------    |
+------+     |       |        |       |     |       |     +------+
             |       |        |       |     |       |
             +-------+        +-------+     +-------+
```

After:

```
head         Node             Node                        tail
+------+     +-------+        +-------+                   +------+
|    ------->|     -----...-->| NULL  |<---------------------    |
+------+     |       |        |       |                   +------+
             |       |        |       |
             +-------+        +-------+
```

To find this node in a singly-linked list requires traversing the list.

To find this node in a doubly-linked list doesn't require traversing the list. We can simply use the pointers stylized as `<===` in the following diagram:

```
head         Node             Node          Node          tail
+------+     +-------+        +-------+     +-------+     +------+
|    ------->|     -----...-->|     ------->| NULL  |<=======    |
+------+     | NULL  |<-...------     |<=======     |     +------+
             |       |        |       |     |       |
             +-------+        +-------+     +-------+
```