# Python double linked list \ single linked list - O(1) notation while running on loop

Tags: python, linked-list, time-complexity, nodes, doubly-linked-list

let us say I have functions I want to build in a double linked list ( or singular one, it doesnt matter ).
How do I reach o(1) notation?
I have the function: return and remove last node.
to get to the last I need to run a while loop to get to the end.
but for that, it will be O(n), not O(1).
I know how to solve it, but I dont understand why it is O(1) and not O(N).

Edit:
My question got answered, thanks to the helpers:
@blhsing and @Mechanic Pig
May close post if needed.

Comment: Maintain the tail node of the linked list.

Comment: @MechanicPig What do you mean?
I have at the init: self.front, self.rear and self.len.
Now, as said to me in the question, self.front is the first node, self.rear is the last.
Does it mean that I can assume that self.rear is the last node or I have to make it like that? If I can assume, so I can just use prev and take that node. but if I cant assume, I need to move self.rear from front to the last node, which then it will be self.rear

Comment: This may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531097/removing-the-tail-of-a-linked-list-with-a-tail-pointer

Comment: @blhsing sadly it is not... I know how to remove the tail, but the question is not said understanable... 
Is self.rear assumed to be the last node? or I need to move it to the last node?

Comment: Yes `self.rear` should be maintained at every update so that it always points to the last node, so that if you need to remove the last node you only need *O(1)* time to reach it.

Comment: @blhsing ohhhh. now I understand, please tell me if I am correctly ( since I understand like a little child ):
At first self.front and self.rear are the same, they are None.
Then with my functions I implement that in a way, I make self.front the head of the linked list. and self.rear will move up towards the end with every function, thus self.rear is the last.
Thanks!

Comment: That's correct. I found a better article for you by the way: https://algorithmtutor.com/Data-Structures/Basic/Doubly-Linked-Lists/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deletion complexity of last element in double linked list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54623809/deletion-complexity-of-last-element-in-double-linked-list)